# populating two different tableviews of two different viewcontroller classes with two different sqlite files data?

Tags: iphone

I am working on an app having tabbarcontroller plus navigation controller.Tabbar controller has two tabbar items.Each tab bar item has a tableview associated with it.i want to populate the two different tableviews with two different sqlite files data.how can i do so?.is there any example related to it..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each UITableView has its own UITableViewController, you can just use the UITableViewDatasource methods in that specific UIViewController, right?

If you're looking at using sqlite databases, you should check out CoreData. It manages a lot of the database communication for you and has the NSFetchedResultsController that updates your UITableView when the underlying data changes.